# Is there a way to capture child process stdout when running within fsanitize when it interrupts / crashes?

Tags: rust, stdout, child-process, address-sanitizer

We have a program to test other programs. It just compares if the output is correct on certain input. I'd like to switch from Valgrind to fsanitize for a few reasons.

The problem is that our Rust program is not able to capture the stdout of the child process with certain errors with fsanitize but when using valgrind all output can be captured.

That would be the child process.

```rust
let mut run_cmd = Command::new(format!("./{}", &self.meta.projdata.project_name))
    //assuming makefile_path = project path
    .current_dir(
        &self
            .meta
            .projdata
            .makefile_path
            .as_ref()
            .unwrap_or(&String::from("./")),
    )
    .args([&self.argv].iter().filter(|s| !s.is_empty()))
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .envs(envs)
    .spawn()
    .expect("could not spawn process");
```

If it's still running after a certain amount of time it's going to be killed.

```rust
fn command_timeout(
    cmd: Child,
    timeout: i32,
    number: i32,
) -> Result<(String, i32), ExecuteError> {
    let mut cmd = cmd;

    let mut output = String::new();

    match cmd
        .wait_timeout(Duration::from_secs(timeout as u64))
        .unwrap()
    {
        Some(expr) => {
            let mut tmp: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

            cmd.stdout
                .as_mut()
                .unwrap()
                .read_to_end(&mut tmp)
                .expect("could not read stdout");

            output = format!("{}{}", output, String::from_utf8_lossy(&tmp));
            let retvar = expr.code().unwrap_or(-1);
            return Ok((output, retvar));
        }
        None => {
            println!("killing {} beacause of timeout", number);
            cmd.kill().expect("Upps, can't kill this one");

            return Err(ExecuteError::Timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this problematic test case would be:

```
./a2 
output1 from c
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==11907==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffef3111660 (pc 0x565288af853a bp 0x7ffef310c8f0 sp 0x7ffef310c820 T0)
    #0 0x565288af853a in main (/home/k/esp/students/assignment2espep_693/a2+0xfc53a)
    #1 0x7fd97bd0c151 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x28151)
    #2 0x565288a1c1cd in _start (/home/k/esp/students/assignment2espep_693/a2+0x201cd)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (/home/k/esp/students/assignment2espep_693/a2+0xfc53a) in main
==11907==ABORTING
```

Example C Code to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char array[1];

    puts("output1 from c");
    array[20000] = 'c';
    printf("output2 from c: %llu\n", (long long unsigned) (array[20000]) ); //this is on purpose
    return 0;
}
```

If I now use the same input file via Rust, the output / tmp variable will be empty. Is there any way to still capture the output when using fsanitize?
I know that fsanitize prints to stderr and this is currently ignored but I don't get it why the output from the child on stdout is also not captured.

The C program is compiled with `clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c17 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address`

It is started with `ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0 ./testrunner`